# What happens when Pran-Pratishta is done to an idol?

Tags: rituals, idols

What happens when Pran-Patithasta is done to an idol ?
Does God start residing in the idol ?

Comment: Technically the pujari that does prana prathistha, his prana resides inside the idol. Anything done to the idol is said to have a corresponding effect on the pujari. So, anyone praying to the idol, starts to get the qualities of the pujari who did prana prathistha with his prana.  There are certain yantras and designs of the temple that also promotes material growth. This is what I've heard.